# Gohighlevel plus twilio and making/triggering an outbound ivr

Tags: ivr, outbound

First, I don't know how to code. Tools I have-twilio, gohighlevel and zapier if needed.

What I'd like to do is to trigger and automated outbound call, based on a tag in ghl, that connects to an ivr.

I built the ivr in console and appears to be working fine when triggered by an inbound call. I'm trying to figure out how to trigger an outbound call using the rest api.

So perfect situation is contact in ghl gets tag applied that triggers the rest api to make an outbound call... GO..! lol